# MySQL-Query too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, select

I am using the following tables in my MySQL-Database:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `company`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `numb` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `cik` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sNumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `street1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateChanged` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `seriesId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `exchange` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cik`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `company` (`numb`, `cik`, `sNumber`, `street1`, `street2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, `name`, `dateChanged`, `name2`, `seriesId`, `symbol`, `exchange`) VALUES
('6798', 'abc', '953551121', '701 AVENUE', '', 'GLENDALE', 'CA', '91201-2349', '818-244-8080', '', '', 'Public Store', '', 'PSA', 'NYSE')


--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `elementname` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `elementvalue` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18439;

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `number`, `elementname`, `date`, `elementvalue`) VALUES
(1, '0001393311-10-000004', 'StockholdersEquityIncludingPortionAttributableToNoncontrollingInterest', '2009-12-31', '3399777000')


--
-- Table structure for table `filing`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filing` (
  `number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `amendment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cik` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accession_number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `filing` (`number`, `file_number`, `type`, `amendment`, `date`, `cik`) VALUES
('0001393311-10-000004', '001-33519', '10-K', 0, '2009-12-31', '0000751653'),
('0000751652-10-000006', '001-08796', '10-K', 0, '2009-12-31', '0000751652')
```

The data table has around 22.000 entries, filing and company tables have around 400 entries each. I want to operate the database with a lot more entries in the future.

I perform the following query, which selects the newest item with a given type:

```
SELECT data.elementname, data.elementvalue, company.name2 FROM data
JOIN filing ON data.number = filing.number
JOIN company ON filing.cik = company.cik
WHERE elementname IN ('Elem1', 'Elem2', 'Elem3', 'Elem4', 'Elem5', 'ElemN')

 AND number IN (
  SELECT number
   FROM filing
   WHERE filing.cik IN ('cik1', 'cik2', 'cikN')
   AND filing.type = '1L'
   GROUP BY filing.cik
)
```

It takes between ~0.28 and 0.4 seconds to complete, which appears to be very slow.

When i perform the query without the following line

```
WHERE filing.cik IN ('cik1', 'cik2', 'cikN')
```

it takes only ~0.035 seconds.

Any idea how to speed the query up or to optimize the table structure because the table is growing rapidly and it's already too slow.

Comment: Use indexes. You have none.

Comment: **[Use the Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)**

Comment: Can you suggest an index for my database? I am not very expirienced in using them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the table structure you posted for `filing` is incorrect, as the primary key you specified doesn't. I'll assume you mean `number`. Additionally, you didn't specify the table definition for `company`, which makes trying to provide advice for this somewhat difficult.

However, both of the comments are correct. You need some indexes. Based on the query, you should probably some the following indexes.

> ALTER TABLE  `company` ADD INDEX (  `cik` )
>   ALTER TABLE  `data` ADD INDEX ( `number` )

I would also recommend taking a look at whether data.elementname actually needs to be a MEDIUMTEXT, which is a pretty huge column. If the rest of the data looks like the example data you provided, you should probably change it into a varchar. TEXT columns can cause some serious performance penalties due to the way they're stored.

Additionally, your PRIMARY KEY number columns, which are currently strings, look as though they could be reformatted into different columns that are actually of type INT. Keep in mind that VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY columns will not be as efficient as INTs, just because they're so much bigger.

Lastly, 22k rows isn't all that much data. You should a take a look at your my.cnf settings. Your key_buffer value may be too small to fit indexes entirely in memory. Additionally, you may want to consider using INNODB for these tables, combined with an innodb_buffer_pool value that'll keep everything in memory.